# Check for (literally) no user input in Python

Tags: python, input, sleep

I would like to know whether if it's possible to get a way of detecting a user not using the input() function for, let's say, 5 seconds.

```
foo_input = input("What's your name? ")
# Some code i don't know?
print("You still there?")
```

Whenever this 5 seconds have passed, the program would ask if the user it's still there.

Is there any way to get this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would `input` return when the user didn't enter something?  *When* would it do so?